# Impossible to remove registry key

Tags: windows-registry

I have a very stubborn registry key which is impossible to delete or access:
`HKLM\Software\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\CurrentVersion`. When I try to open it in `regedit`, it says `"An error is preventing this key from being opened.  Details: The system cannot find the file specified."`

When I try to delete the whole branch, all I get is `"Error while deleting key"`.

Following some advice I found elsewhere, I tried downloading the [RegDelNull utility](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/regdelnull) from Sysinternals, but scanning the whole `HKLM` tree did not reveal any items to delete. However, when I specified the entire path to the bad key, I got the following message:

```
"A null context handle was passed from the client to the host during a remote procedure call."
```

**Why did regedit complain about being unable to find the file specified? Is it something related to the way registry entries are stored?**

**More importantly, how do I delete the keys when they cannot even be deleted by the utility made for precisely this purpose?**

Comment: What is the path to the key, and do you have permissions for it?

Comment: Key added. Being the admin of the system, I have all the permissions I should need.

Comment: Not necessarily - registry keys have their own permissions (right click -> Permissions). Make sure administrators/your account has permission to modify.

Comment: A permission problem would manifest differently though, wouldn't it? I have checked though and have both read and write permissions set to Allow for the account I'm using.

Comment: Some keys need "full access," not just read-write. For my system builds, there's at least one registry key I have to go give full access to my account (or all accounts).

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to say is that I have "Read" and "Full control" privileges. There's no "Write" permission, apparently my brain just made that up when seeing "Read" :-)

Comment: You did pass the `-s` flag to RegDelNull, right? Can you use RegEdit's *Permissions* UI to take ownership of the key?

Comment: Is Symantec EP still installed/running on the system?

Comment: You may have to change the owner in permissions for that registry key.

Comment: @BenN: Sure I did. The owner is the Administrators group which I am a member of.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: No, it was removed, although apparently not as cleanly as I would like it to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue on my Windows 7 box. I eventually figured out that the key was a broken symbolic link. The built-in `regedit` tool does not seem to properly support these, and acts as described when trying to access such a key.

I managed to delete the broken symbolic link using https://github.com/tenox7/regln like this:

```
C:\Users\Zero3\Desktop>regln-x64.exe -d "\Registry\User\S-1-5-21-1688150413-3759
594893-2435602081-1000\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Shell Extension
s\Approved"
```

You will need to adapt the path to your use case, of course.

(For reference, I noted that a similar issue was posted here: https://serverfault.com/questions/796797/regedit-error-cannot-find-the-file-specified-accessing-key/963975)